# MVC data annotations on model without mvc dependency?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, class

Lets say I have a project that contains all of my model classes, with a separate project containing an MVC 4 web application, (service,repository layers too).

If I want to use MVC specific data annotations for my model properties, how do i do this without having a dependency to MVC?

Any non MVC projects referencing the model would also require the MVC references. I would prefer that these are only added when the models are used by MVC and not everything.

Initially i was thinking partial classes but i know these cannot be used cross assembly.

Making clone classes and inheriting from the originals outside the model classes might not work. It would require the code to refer to these child classes instead of the originals.

I would prefer a more unobtrusive manner of attaching attributes to the model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If I want to use MVC specific data annotations for my model
>   properties, how do i do this without having a dependency to MVC?

By using view models. View models are classes that you design and define in your MVC application and which are the classes that get passed to your views. You should never pass your models to the views. Your controller actions could query your service layer for domain models, then map those domain models to view models and pass those view models to the views. On the other hand your `[HttpPost]` controller actions should take view models wit htheir respective data annotations as arguments, map those view models to their corresponding domain models and pass the domain models to your service layer.

Comment: Should view models inherit from models or simply act as a container for the complete object?

Comment: ViewModel should definitely NOT inherit from a model. They act as a separation between your model and your view by only allowing operation (and properties) required by the view. Either you can have a reference to the model in your view model but not expose it publicly or emulate a part of the model that you can then map (manually or with the help of external libraries to ease the pain).

Comment: So duplication of the model properties within the view model and  the validation attributes attached to those. Some kind of translation between the view model and model would be required inside the handling action to extract the relevant data though?

Comment: Yes indeed some sort of translation between view models and models is needed and I suggest you use AutoMapper for handling those operations. https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper

Comment: The only disadvantage i see to using viewmodels instead of models, in our current setup we fetch object data in the model binder and populate the posted object and related objects. So objects posted to actions are pre-fetched.